# Pandas Dataframe flatten crosstab with multilevel index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an Excel file which looks like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       | Cat1  | Cat1  | Cat1  | Cat1  | Cat1  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       | Type1 | Type1 | Type1 | Type1 | Type2 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       | 2018  | 2018  | 2018  | 2018  | 2018  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Name  | 1Q    | 2Q    | 3Q    | 4Q    | 1Q    |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Name1 | 1     | 5     | 3     | 5     | 4     |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Name2 | 3     | 23    | 4     | 2     | 4     |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Name3 | 4     | 3     | 5     | 3     | 44    |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Name4 | 3     | 6     | 5     | 4     | 2     |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

...and so on

I want to format it so that it looks like this:

```
+-------+------+-------+------+---------+-------+
| Name  | Cat  | Type  | Year | Quarter | Value |
+-------+------+-------+------+---------+-------+
| Name1 | Cat1 | Type1 | 2018 | 1Q      | 5     |
+-------+------+-------+------+---------+-------+
| Name1 | Cat1 | Type1 | 2018 | 2Q      | 3     |
+-------+------+-------+------+---------+-------+
| Name1 | Cat1 | Type1 | 2018 | 3Q      | 5     |
+-------+------+-------+------+---------+-------+
| Name1 | Cat1 | Type1 | 2018 | 4Q      | 4     |
+-------+------+-------+------+---------+-------+
| Name1 | Cat1 | Type2 | 2018 | 1Q      | 6     |
+-------+------+-------+------+---------+-------+
```

I've loaded it into a pandas DataFrame and am unsure how to proceed now. Is it melt, stack, unstack, MultiIndex...?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
print (df.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['Cat1'], ['Type1', 'Type2'], ['2018'], ['1Q', '2Q', '3Q', '4Q']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 0]])


df = df.stack([0,1,2,3]).reset_index()
df.columns = ['Name','Cat','Type','Year','Quarter','Value']
print (df)
     Name   Cat   Type  Year Quarter  Value
0   Name1  Cat1  Type1  2018      1Q    1.0
1   Name1  Cat1  Type1  2018      2Q    5.0
2   Name1  Cat1  Type1  2018      3Q    3.0
3   Name1  Cat1  Type1  2018      4Q    5.0
4   Name1  Cat1  Type2  2018      1Q    4.0
5   Name2  Cat1  Type1  2018      1Q    3.0
6   Name2  Cat1  Type1  2018      2Q   23.0
7   Name2  Cat1  Type1  2018      3Q    4.0
8   Name2  Cat1  Type1  2018      4Q    2.0
9   Name2  Cat1  Type2  2018      1Q    4.0
10  Name3  Cat1  Type1  2018      1Q    4.0
11  Name3  Cat1  Type1  2018      2Q    3.0
12  Name3  Cat1  Type1  2018      3Q    5.0
13  Name3  Cat1  Type1  2018      4Q    3.0
14  Name3  Cat1  Type2  2018      1Q   44.0
15  Name4  Cat1  Type1  2018      1Q    3.0
16  Name4  Cat1  Type1  2018      2Q    6.0
17  Name4  Cat1  Type1  2018      3Q    5.0
18  Name4  Cat1  Type1  2018      4Q    4.0
19  Name4  Cat1  Type2  2018      1Q    2.0
```

Comment: I get the following error:
IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2

Comment: Can you create `dict` from your sample data? `d = df.to_dict()`. Thanks

Comment: Yes I can, no errors are returned. At the moment my columns look like: "Unnamed: 2" etc. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: Maybe youir real data are a bit different, hard to know.

Comment: So if data not confidental the best is create pickel file and upload to `gdocs`, `dropbox` or send me data in email from my profile. `df.to_pickle('data.pkl')`

Comment: It is confidential unfortunately. It does match the format that I've outlined above though.

Comment: Ok, so what return `print (df.columns.nlevels)` ?

Comment: and `print (df.index.nlevels)` of original data

Comment: df.index.nlevels = 1
df.columns.nlevels = 1

Comment: So now it is clear. You need `df = df.read_excel(file, header=[0,1,2,3])`

Comment: You need `MultiIndex` from your headers.

Comment: Thanks for your help thus far! I'm unsure how to proceed. Would I use MultiIndex from tuples?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Use [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html)